# Glass Mapper set Sitecore Context

Tags: glass-mapper

I am receiving the following error using Glass Mapper

```
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException : The given key was not present in the dictionary.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at Glass.Mapper.AbstractService..ctor(String contextName)
   at Glass.Mapper.Sc.SitecoreService..ctor(Database database, String contextName)
   at Glass.Mapper.Sc.ItemExtensions.GlassCast[T](Item item, Boolean isLazy, Boolean inferType)
```

Here are the details of my configuration. I'm using a unit test project that has the same Glass Mapper version installed as the project it tests. My `GlassMapperScCustom.cs` in the Unit Test Project is below:

```
    public static class GlassMapperScCustom
    {
        public static void CastleConfig(IWindsorContainer container)
        {
            var config = new Config();

            container.Install(new SitecoreInstaller(config));
        }

        public static IConfigurationLoader[] GlassLoaders()
        {
            return new IConfigurationLoader[] { };
        }
        public static void PostLoad()
        {

        }
    }
```

Additionally, I have `GlassMapper.Sc.Mvc.config` in the `App_Config` folder and that is the only one.

The exception above occurs when the Code Under Test (CUT) calls the following line:

`var paths = pathFolder.GetChildren().Select(child => child.GlassCast<Path>());`

Based on what I've searched online, I need to be able to set the SitecoreContext in order for GlassMapper to work correctly. How and where would I do that; in the unit test project or the CUT project? Or is this some other issue entirely?

**Edit:**

Here are the Glass Mapper versions:

```
<package id="Glass.Mapper" version="3.0.13.25" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Glass.Mapper.Sc" version="3.2.2.45" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Glass.Mapper.Sc.CastleWindsor" version="3.2.1.23" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc-5" version="3.2.1.42" targetFramework="net461" />
```

Comment: what version of glass mapper do you have?

Comment: I updated the question to include the versions from my package config in the unit test project.

Comment: Can you check if you deploy Website\App_Config\Include\Glass.Mapper.Sc.CastleWindsor.config file

Comment: @uioporqwerty Has something from my answer failed to work for you?

Comment: Sorry, it's a very well written answer but it hasn't resolved my issue yet. Based on the Glass Mapper version we're using, we don't have the .Cast<T> method for sitecorecontext. I've tried using  
`var context = new SitecoreContext(Context.Database);
 var paths = pathFolder.GetChildren().Select(child => context.CreateType<=Path>(child));` which is the recommended way of glass mapping for this version of glass mapper. But the same error occurs on the first line which leads me to believe there is a problem with SitecoreFakeDb and not Glass Mapper itself.

Comment: @uioporqwerty Have you tried preceding your code with the part of my answer that starts with `if (Glass.Mapper.Context.Default == null)`?

Comment: I can't use that code since the version of GlassMapper are different. That code seems like it would work for GlassMapper 4+. I feel as if it is a configuration issue with Glass Mapper on the unit test project side.

Comment: Have you considered upgrading to the latest Glass?

Answer (score 4):

### Unit testing

Your question says that your tests are unit tests, so first I'll talk about a proper unit testing approach. Such tests should be run in isolation, meaning that your module shouldn't rely on data coming from a Sitecore database. You should provide mocks for all data consumed by code under test.

To make this possible, you'll need to ensure that the module does not rely on static context. Instead, it should employ Dependency Injection to obtain dependencies.

In this case, the module should be injected with `Glass.Mapper.Sc.ISitecoreContext` and use it for all Glass operations. Here's an example:

```
public class SomeModule
{
    private readonly ISitecoreContext _sitecoreContext;

    public SomeModule(ISitecoreContext context)
    {
        this._sitecoreContext = context;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // ...
        IEnumerable<Item> pathItems = ...;
        var paths = pathItems.Select(child => this._sitecoreContext.Cast<Path>(child));
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then in the Unit test code you will instantiate the module with a mock implementation of `ISitecoreContext` passed into its constructor. You can either create your own mock implementation (it's pretty easy), or you can use mocking frameworks, such as [NSubstitute](https://nsubstitute.github.io/), [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq4), [FakeItEasy](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy) or [Rhino Mocks](https://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/oss/rhino-mocks).

### Integration testing

Tests that actually get data from an external storage are not considered unit tests, they are called integration tests.

To make tests run outside of a Sitecore page context, you will need to manually create some dependencies, such as the Glass `ISitecoreContext`, and pass them into the module being tested. This means you should *still* apply exactly the same approach (as if you were unit testing) to the design of `SomeModule`—it should accept `ISitecoreContext` as a constructor argument and use it for accessing Sitecore data. The only difference will be that your test code will inject a real context instance into the module.

Here's how you can do it:

```
// Prepare the environment
if (Glass.Mapper.Context.Default == null)
{
    var config = new Glass.Mapper.Sc.Config();
    var dependencyResolver = new Glass.Mapper.Sc.IoC.DependencyResolver(config);
    Glass.Mapper.Context.Create(dependencyResolver, "Default", true);
}

// Create the Sitecore context
Database db = Factory.GetDatabase("master");
var sitecoreContext = new SitecoreContext(db);

// Instantiate the module and use it
var module = new SomeModule(sitecoreContext);
module.SomeMethod();
```